# AppleScriptTask is not returning Result to VBA

Tags: macos, excel, applescript, vba

I am seeing very intermittent return results when I have a Mac Excel VBA Macro calling an Apple script using AppleScriptTask.

I say intermittent because I can run the same code the same way and sometimes I get the result I expect and other times I get a blank string.

When I call the `GetPathInput` Function below with the following line I get the intermittent behavior I described:

```
customerDataDir = GetPathInput("Please select the directory you would like to use for Customer Data Output:" & userHomeDir & "Documents/Data/Customers/")
```

VBA Macro:

```
Function GetPathInput(ParameterStr As String) As String
Dim answer As Integer
answer = vbNo
Do Until answer = vbYes
    GetPathInput = AppleScriptTask("GetUserInput.scpt", "GetPathInput", ParameterStr)
    answer = MsgBox("Path: " & GetPathInput, vbYesNo, "Is this what you selected?")
Loop
End Function
```

AppleScript GetUserInput.scpt:

```
on GetPathInput(ParameterStr)
-- Takes 2 Parameters (Prompt for the Dialog, Default Path) 
set myParm to my splitParameters(ParameterStr, ":")
set PromptStr to item 1 of myParm
set DefaultPathStr to item 2 of myParm
return POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt PromptStr default location DefaultPathStr) as string
--  set DefaultPathStr to POSIX path of (path to home folder as string)
--  display dialog PathNameStr default answer DefaultPathStr
--  return text returned of result
end GetPathInput
```

AppleScript splitParameters:

```
on splitParameters(theString, theDelimiter)
-- save delimiters to restore old settings
set oldDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
-- set delimiters to delimiter to be used
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theDelimiter
-- create the array
set theArray to every text item of theString
-- restore the old setting
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelimiters
-- return the result
return theArray
end splitParameters
```